# Разные действия при четном/нечетном срабатывании события

Tags: алгоритм

Есть layout1, при нажатии на который что-то там происходит по сценарию№1. 
Но, если кликнуть по layout1 второй раз, то что-то там происходит по сценарию№2.

Не могу понять, как написать условие для метода onClick (или onTouch) для layout1 так, чтобы при очередном клике по нему попеременно  происходило то то, что заложено в сценарии№1, то то, что заложено в сценарии№2. 
Т.е. как прописать условие в скобках после if в такой конструкции:

```
if (layout1 нажат первый раз) {что-то происходит, неважно что} 
else (layout1 нажат второй раз) {что-то другое происходит, неважно что}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зарегистрируйте в классе `boolean`-переменную `firstClick`, которая по умолчанию равна `true` и проверяйте её значение.

```
if(firstClick) {
    // first click code
} else {
    // second click code
}

firstClick = !firstClick;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean scene = true;

@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (scene){ что-то происходит; }
            else { что-то другое происходит; }

            scene = !scene;

}
```